# Post All Friends Who Are Using The Facebook Application

Tags: php, facebook

I'd like to post the profile pics of all of the friends of the user currently using the app, that have installed the app. Is there someway to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, but you have to do it locally, facebook doesn't automatically do this for you. Here's a way of achieving this:

When a user comes to your application for the first time facebook sends you some data regarding that user. What you need from this data is the id of the user. Store this id in your database. Later on, do a search by id in your database to find friends of the current user in your table. If you find any it means that those friends are using/have used your application.

For example, if you have your table with a field named `id` and the friends id list = 1, 2, 3, 4, etc. the corresponding query would be:

```
SELECT id from users WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

At this step you can easily fetch each user photo using the graph API, like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/ID_OF_THE_USER/picture
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Alternatively you may use FQL to get the user's friends and whether they have authorised the app (`is_app_user`).

Comment: Thanks guys! I'll try both options.